# AngularJS PHP session not terminating on browser close

Tags: php, angularjs, session

Friends,
I am new to AngularJS and need your help to solve an issue.
I created a session in PHP after passing ID & Pass from ANGULAR ... it works fine but the session is not terminated if browser is closed.
Friends can u guide me how to fix this issue?

SESSION.PHP

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$UserTryName = $user->username;
$UserTryPass = $user->password;
$IDcheck = $mysqli->query("SELECT role FROM users WHERE name =    '$UserTryName' AND password = '$UserTryPass' ");
 $row_cnt = $IDcheck->num_rows;
if($row_cnt > 0) { 
while($row = $IDcheck->fetch_array()) { 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['uid'] = uniqid('ang_');
    print $_SESSION['uid'];
}
}
```

Comment: Would this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146647/destroy-php-session-on-closing

Comment: no my friend, session do get destroy when i execute the logout function but not on closing the browser

Comment: That depends on browsers also, try a javascript function to detect the browser closing and execute a final logout.

Comment: Friend i want to learn about what i did wrong