# Session is not destroyed even after closing browser

Tags: php, session

I'm building a site (e-commerce) which stores session_id in DB 
(Generated by `$session = session_id();` ). I need to destroy it once checkout completes. I've added

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

at the end, but a simple print shows that session_id() is not being destroyed and is the same even after checkout. How can I completely destroy that. As you probably know, Firefox destroys all session on close while Chrome does not. I'm trying to destroy the session_id() generated. Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destroy PHP Session on closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146647/destroy-php-session-on-closing)

Comment: Have you tried to prevent storing cookies by calling session_set_cookie_params(0); before session start?

Comment: @AkhilBalakrishnan in will  try

Answer (score 0):

So after thinking and surfing the internet, Many people said that it is a bad idea (not sure why) to store id generated from `session_id()`
So, instead I used `uniqid()` 
I do something like this to generate the id on the first page and then start the session on every page and get its value via `$_SESSION`

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['session_id']))
{
    $session = uniqid();
    $_SESSION['session_id'] = $session;
}
else
{
    $session = $_SESSION['session_id'];
}
```

Turns out, this solved my problem. I can easily `session_unset(); / session_destroy();` the session at the final checkout step (where cart is dumped)

Comment: Session is usually stored in a cookie and your server just reuses the same session ID the client previously had.

Comment: @sashok_bg which is really cool.. If the user adds items to cart and then re-opens the website and it's still there. But, only if they're using Chrome :P