# Session Destory after close browser and new user login in php

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have 3 role and each role i have stored in different session variable.
if i am login with admin1 and close the browser without logout,and agin login with admin2,this time admin1 session is apearing.

for new admin new session variable should work,if i am doing this in private window its working fine.

so how to destroy/replace the pervious seesion while closing the browser.

```html
$admin1_sessionObj = new Zend\Session\Container('Admin1Session');
admin2_sessionObj = new Zend\Session\Container('Admin2Session');
admin3_sessionObj = new Zend\Session\Container('Admin3Session');
$sessionObj = ''; 
if(isset($admin1_sessionObj->sess_role_id) && !empty($admin1_sessionObj->sess_role_id)) {
  $sessionObj = $admin1_sessionObj;
} elseif (isset(admin2_sessionObj->sess_role_id) && !empty(admin2_sessionObj->sess_role_id)) {
  $sessionObj = admin2_sessionObj;
}
elseif (isset(admin3_sessionObj->sess_role_id) && !empty(admin3_sessionObj->sess_role_id)) {
  $sessionObj = admin3_sessionObj;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destroy PHP Session on closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146647/destroy-php-session-on-closing)

Comment: Sessions expire after a period of inactivity. Don't worry about it. Just let PHP take care of it.